# Can't sort column with ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

In ExtJs 3.4 application i have a store:

```
    var roadStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    url:url_servlet+"/roadsJson.jsp?type=summer",
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'data',
          }, [ {
             name : 'name', sortType : 'string', mapping :'name'
          },{
             name : 'road_id', sortType : 'string', mapping :'road_id'
        }]
    ),
});
```

And columns model:

```
            columns:[
            {id:"column1", header:'Название дороги',width:300,sortable: true,dataIndex:'name'},
            {id:"column2", header:'Id',width:300,dataIndex:'road_id',hidden:true}],
```

And a problem: columns not sortible. I click on column header but sort not work. Whats can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `sortType : 'string'`. It can be just:

```
sortType : 'asDate'
sortType : 'asFloat'
sortType : 'asInt'
sortType : 'asText'
sortType : 'asUCString'
sortType : 'asUCText'
```

See documentation for more information: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.SortTypes

Comment: I try asUCString and get error: `TypeError: d is not a function`. With other same.

Comment: Something strange here. I remove sortType and sorting start to work. Now how can i make custom sorting?